# Writing custom context selector log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I have an application which is a standalone Java Program. It instantiates several threads for different service jobs. Each service job has a separate log4j2 configuration which writes to separate log files. So, I need to have a custom context selector which can store and give contexts based for the corresponding job thread.

I have tried to search everywhere even the log4j manual but not found any reference.
Can someone help me writing a custom context selector? I am using log4j2 version 2.5

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this @Tarun?

Answer (score 0):

For reference you can take a look at the [AsyncLoggerContextSelector](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncLoggerContextSelector.java). However, I'm not sure that this approach will solve the problem you described.

If all you need is a thread (or a group of threads) writing to the same log file, you can just use the [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender). The FAQ has [an example](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files) of using the ThreadContext to route log statements from different threads to different log files.

I'm not sure how to achieve this with a context selector.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.